# Best way to import CSV data in a python tensor for machine learning?

Tags: python, neural-network, pytorch, tensor

I want to import a csv data file in python in order to create a neural network down the road (with pytorch). The file has 4 columns and around 1000 rows with first row as titles. Which is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Just use [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/).

In particular what you need is the `read_csv` function.

```
import pandas as pd

...

dataframe = pd.read_csv("/location/file.csv")
```

Check out the [pandas references](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Can you convert to excel and then try this?

```
DF = pd.read_excel (r'Q:\YourPathway\DOCNAME.xlsx', sheet_name='Sheet1')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try numpy.

```
import torch
import numpy as np

...

class DiabetesDataset(Dataset):
    """ Diabetes dataset."""
    # Initialize your data, download, etc.
    def __init__(self):
        xy = np.loadtxt('./data/diabetes.csv.gz', delimiter=',', dtype=np.float32)
        self.len = xy.shape[0]
        self.x_data = from_numpy(xy[:, 0:-1])
        self.y_data = from_numpy(xy[:, [-1]])

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        return self.x_data[index], self.y_data[index]

    def __len__(self):
        return self.len

dataset = DiabetesDataset()
train_loader = DataLoader(dataset=dataset,
                          batch_size=32,
                          shuffle=True,
                          num_workers=2)
```

Full example here: https://github.com/hunkim/PyTorchZeroToAll/blob/master/08_2_dataset_loade_logistic.py